# Progress Bar in dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I am trying to make Progress bar in Dialogue in my android app so that when a user presses a button dialogue box appears with text like "Please wait" and a moving progress bar. I don't know how to do this.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.progressdialog;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pleasewait();
    }



    public void pleasewait(View v){

   pd.setTitle(“Hello”);


           pd.show();
    }

}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please wait…"
        android:onClick=”pleasewait” />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please make corrections in my code or, if you can, suggest some better way.

**When i tried suggestions**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 Button button;
 ProgressDialog progressDoalog;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      progressDoalog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
      progressDoalog.setMax(100);
      progressDoalog.setMessage("Its loading....");
      progressDoalog.setTitle("ProgressDialog bar example");
      progressDoalog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
      progressDoalog.show();
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                        try {
     while (progressDoalog.getProgress() <= progressDoalog
    .getMax()) {
       Thread.sleep(200);
       handle.sendMessage(handle.obtainMessage());
       if (progressDoalog.getProgress() == progressDoalog
    .getMax()) {
         progressDoalog.dismiss();
       }
     }
          } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
        }
      }).start();
    }

    Handler handle = new Handler() {
    @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        progressDoalog.incrementProgressBy(1);
      }
    };
  });
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items 
                //to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return true;
 }

}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyy4wyjvx7w8eoy/ProgressDialog.zip?dl=0)

In Short :

```
Example:

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
//in the class...
private ProgressDialog progressBar;

//when you want the dialog to show the first time.
progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "Disconnecting", "Please wait for few secs...");

//when you want the progressbar to disappear
if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
progressBar.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Yes sure!:) may be i am missing to import something.

Comment: @metno I am getting errors with this code. please have a look i added picture.     And i tried but cant post in chat now...i dont have prevelege:(

Comment: After Adding import this code is working perfectly..Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to declare a progress dialog

`ProgressDialog progress;`

Show it wit its data like here

`progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title","dialog message", true);`

and than dismiss it whenever you have to

`progress.dismiss();`